# How to use regex to find url in the css string

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a hard time with extracting the url in a text using python

I got the text from style attribute of a tag with beautiful soup, the text is always:

```
background:url(//somedomaine.com/annonces/103028/large.jpg) no-repeat center center
```

My goal is to extract "//somedomaine.com/annonces/103028/large.jpg" but I'm new with regex, I tried to use the "$" modifier with "url" but it didn't help.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an incredibly generic match:

```
text = "background:url(//somedomaine.com/annonces/103028/large.jpg) no-repeat center center"
regstr = r"background:url\((.*)\) no-repeat center center"

import re
x = re.match(regstr, text)
print(x.group(1))  # '//somedomaine.com/annonces/103028/large.jpg'
```

The regex here is very straightforward - match the largest possible set of arbitrary characters `(.*)` surrounded by the given text (`"background:url("` in the front, `") no-repeat center center"` in the back).

Answer (score 3):

`background:url\(([^\)]+)\)`

This regex will look for the text `background:url(`, and thencapture everything up until the first `)` it encounters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CazV40/1/)

Comment: Couldn't you just do a non-greedy match there and the character group wouldn't be necessary? `\((.+?)\)`?

Comment: You absolutely could, and it would satisfy OP's requirements, too (hence my upvote on your answer). My answer was just force of habit - whenever HTML/CSS is involved, I often use negated character classes, since they'll match across lines. It improves flexibility, since HTML/CSS lets the tag opening and closing be on different lines.

Comment: You are not accounting for spaces between background and url and many more things...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *non-regex* solution and just search for substring,

```
url = text[text.find('url(') + 4: text.find(')')]
```

Not robust for urls containing `)|url(`